# Install Package 2sic_2SexyContent_08.12.00_Install Fails in a DNN Azure Web App

Tags: azure, web, 2sxc

I have installed the following packages into our Dev systems with no failures.

- 2sic_2SexyContent_08.12.00_Install
- 2sic_2SexyContent_09.43.02_Install
- 2sic_2SexyContent_10.25.02_Install

However, when I try to run these in our production DNN Evoq 9.1.1 site that is running in a Azure Web App, I am getting errors with the database entries and a failed installation. In short, the errors are about passing Null values into database objects. Unfortunately, I do not have any logs to share, but was wondering if anyone else has had a similar issue with installing 2sxc in sites running with Azure Web Apps. Azure leverages more control on the SQL Server and databases than a traditional set up. Currently this production site has a 2sxc 7.1.2 and I want to upgrade it to 10.25.02.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow :) I'm one of the core developers of 2sxc but I can't help you with this. Various people run 2sxc on Azure, so I'm not sure if your setup is special or if it's really something with 2sxc. If you do find out what causes it, we would be glad to hear about it.

Comment: Thanks. The current 2sxc version is 7.1.2 and it runs in the Azure Web App. It is just the install packages for the newer versions that throws an error and does not complete. These same packages ran fine in a non-Azure Web App and threw no errors. As far as I am aware we do not have any special settings on our SQL db provided with the Azure Web App. It is all using the default settings.